# Accessing Django View data fro JavaScript using Fetch Api

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get data from Django view using fetch API but the fetch API isn't reaching the Django view.

```
    function connect(username) {
    alert('connect');
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // get a token from the back end
        let data;
        alert("before append")

        // data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $('#csrf- 
      helperinput[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value'));
        alert("vc")
        fetch("/videocall/", {
            method: 'POST',
            // headers: {
            //     "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
            //     "Accept": "application/json",
            //     "Content-Type": "application/json"
            // },
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', //Necessary to work with request.is_ajax()
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },
            //credentials: "same-origin",
            body: JSON.stringify({'username': username})
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(_data => {
            // join video call
            alert("Joint")
            data = _data;
            return Twilio.Video.connect(data.token);
        }).then(_room => {
          alert("room")
            room = _room;
            room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);
            room.on('participantConnected', participantConnected);
            room.on('participantDisconnected', participantDisconnected);
            connected = true;
            updateParticipantCount();
            connectChat(data.token, data.conversation_sid);
            resolve();
        }).catch(e => {
          alert("catch")
            console.log(e);
            reject();
        });
        alert(promise)

    });
    return promise;
    };
```

Here's my django view

```
    def videocall(request):
    print("Trying to login")
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Trying to login")
```

It's not even printing trying to login which i printed in django view. I think there's some problem in URL in fetch.
I'm new to Django please help me in this regard

Comment: Try checking your browser console... There should be some error messages showing up that could help you pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but this code below is working fine both for *get* and *post* requests in Django 3.1.4 and Python 3.8.

```
//js
const AssignStaffForm = () => {
  fetch('/app/get_users/', {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        // then I use this data in an html form.
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err in fetch", err);
    });
};

#url dispatcher
path('get_users/', views.get_users, name='get_users'),


#view
import json
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def get_users(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users=[]
        for user in User.objects.all():
            users.append({'id':user.id, 'name': user.get_full_name()})
        data = json.dumps({'users': users})
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

## Note:

I had earlier split my views and forgot to delete the original view functions from the main view file and this seemed to be the cause of the error in my case.